# How to use external function on Pandas groupby()?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, data-science

## Background

So I have an ensemble based model and I want to post process the labels I got from N detectors. To do so I want to use the groupby functionality to group detentions in each frame by IOU function that I've build. This will help me making a decision for each group of detection and avoid multiple detection on the same area of the frame.

**Q:** What is the proper return value to the groupby function?

**Pandas groupby documentation says:**

```
by : mapping, function, label, or list of labels
            Used to determine the groups for the groupby.
            If ``by`` is a function, it's called on each value of the object's
            index. If a dict or Series is passed, the Series or dict VALUES
            will be used to determine the groups (the Series' values are first
            aligned; see ``.align()`` method). If an ndarray is passed, the
            values are used as-is determine the groups. A label or list of
            labels may be passed to group by the columns in ``self``. Notice
            that a tuple is interpreted a (single) key.
```

A sample of my data:

```
           xmin      ymin      xmax    ...      confidence  class  frame_idx
25092  0.740968  0.379832  0.837317    ...        0.931677    2.0      988.0
25093  0.342227  0.272692  0.421934    ...        0.904239    2.0      988.0
25094  0.624577  0.333927  0.739960    ...        0.854978    2.0      988.0
25095  0.229680  0.260676  0.272042    ...        0.708415    2.0      988.0
25096  0.420753  0.291226  0.514133    ...        0.610117    2.0      988.0
25097  0.061343  0.265538  0.110653    ...        0.369827    2.0      988.0
25098  0.486258  0.711575  0.558676    ...        0.173804    2.0      988.0
25099  0.069983  0.596780  0.571130    ...        0.145625    2.0      988.0
25100  0.756423  0.693024  0.818869    ...        0.126882    1.0      988.0
25101  0.448371  0.000000  0.628947    ...        0.124258    1.0      988.0
25102  0.664900  0.808117  0.728619    ...        0.119267    2.0      988.0
25103  0.000000  0.776122  0.407657    ...        0.119260    2.0      988.0
25104  0.796306  0.878808  0.844132    ...        0.115530    1.0      988.0
25105  0.006830  0.000000  0.045303    ...        0.110469    1.0      988.0
```

---

## EDIT

I've added my group detections function, currently it return the detections and a list of indices grouped in a list

```
def group_detections(dets, thresh=0.5):
    # NOTE!!! - We assume all dets are from the same class!!!
    # thresh = IoU threshold for box elimination (lower - eliminate more boxes)
    # initialize the list of picked groups
    groups = []
    # if there are no boxes, return an empty list
    if dets.size == 0:
        return dets, groups

    # sort by descending quality
    dets = dets[(-dets[:, 4]).argsort(), :]

    # grab the coordinates of the bounding boxes
    x1 = dets[:, 0]
    y1 = dets[:, 1]
    x2 = dets[:, 2]
    y2 = dets[:, 3]

    # compute the area of the bounding boxes and sort the bounding
    # boxes by the bottom-right y-coordinate of the bounding box
    area = (x2 - x1) * (y2 - y1)
    # keep looping while some indexes still remain in the indexes
    # list
    all_idxs = np.arange(dets.shape[0])[::-1]
    while len(all_idxs) > 0:
        # grab the last index in the indexes list and add the
        # index value to the list of picked indexes
        i = all_idxs[-1]

        # find the largest (x, y) coordinates for the start of
        # the bounding box and the smallest (x, y) coordinates
        # for the end of the bounding box
        xx1 = np.maximum(x1[i], x1[all_idxs[:-1]])
        yy1 = np.maximum(y1[i], y1[all_idxs[:-1]])
        xx2 = np.minimum(x2[i], x2[all_idxs[:-1]])
        yy2 = np.minimum(y2[i], y2[all_idxs[:-1]])

        # compute the width and height of the bounding box
        w = np.maximum(0, xx2 - xx1)
        h = np.maximum(0, yy2 - yy1)

        # compute the ratio of overlap
        overlap = (w * h) / area[all_idxs[:-1]]

        # delete all indexes from the index list that have
        group_idxs = [i] + list(all_idxs[np.where(overlap > thresh)[0]])
        groups.append(group_idxs)
        remove_idxs = np.concatenate(([len(all_idxs) - 1], np.where(overlap > thresh)[0]))
        all_idxs = np.delete(all_idxs, remove_idxs)
    return dets, groups
```

Output example:
dets:

```
array([[0.70187318, 0.37271658, 0.72741735, 0.4855186 , 0.37807396,
        1.        , 0.        ],
       [0.15145046, 0.28159913, 0.1774891 , 0.33394483, 0.30386543,
        1.        , 0.        ],
       [0.51533937, 0.27924138, 0.5292989 , 0.33969468, 0.19332546,
        1.        , 0.        ],
       [0.78109378, 0.87562817, 0.82961792, 1.        , 0.13274428,
        1.        , 0.        ],
       [0.14983323, 0.28213197, 0.16887194, 0.33710539, 0.12764682,
        1.        , 0.        ],
       [0.14637044, 0.033903  , 0.26365086, 0.57686102, 0.12654687,
        1.        , 0.        ],
       [0.22914155, 0.26150814, 0.27148777, 0.31108513, 0.10923221,
        1.        , 0.        ],
       [0.18359725, 0.02795739, 0.23144765, 0.4838326 , 0.10619797,
        1.        , 0.        ],
       [0.22894984, 0.28633049, 0.24446395, 0.35711476, 0.10326774,
        1.        , 0.        ],
       [0.15507454, 0.2818917 , 0.18600157, 0.34016567, 0.10280589,
        1.        , 0.        ],
       [0.0071237 , 0.        , 0.04561174, 0.08170507, 0.10274705,
        1.        , 0.        ],
       [0.74405503, 0.38016886, 0.8356874 , 0.4577626 , 0.10082066,
        1.        , 0.        ]])
```

groups:

```
[[0], [1, 9, 4], [2], [3], [5, 8, 7, 6], [10], [11]]
```

Comment: Please share your function and if possible an expected output.

Comment: I can share it but I just want to know what is the expected return value

Comment: Its not clear to me what you want as output, if you can share what you want as expected output after the groupby, we can help with maybe other methods.

Comment: So I have multiple detections from few detectors, I want to decide which are reffering to the same object, I have a function that does that I just want to integrate it into the groupby pandas function so I can get a groupby object.

Comment: you might want to consider numpy vectorized iou as you have lots of computing to do